# Mail reloads all messages periodically

Tags: email, nokia-lumia-920, gmail

Every month or two, mail reloads all of the messages on my account.  This shows that I have hundreds of new messages, when only a few of them are really new.  What's going on?

I don't know how much of this matters, but the This email account is set up for gmail.  The email account is for gmail, but there are several non gmail accounts that feed into it.  A different gmail account does not seem to have this behavior.  Phone is a Nokia Lumia 920 running Windows Phone 8.0.10211.204.

Comment: How do these email feed to gmail? pop?

Comment: Yes.  They feed using POP3.

Comment: Are you changing anything about these messages (such as flagging them) from other clients?

Comment: Yes. I use gmail on a PC.

Comment: To further confuse matters. This is happening much less frequently over the past few months.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have set the phone to delete the mails older than two months, and to download every message? That way, every couple of months it deletes the old ones and downloads them again

Comment: It was set to Download email from any time.

Comment: Maybe It is the Gmail config the one that only downloads the most recent messages. Have you checked that on the web client configuration?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that @user1876542.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Because you have set the download email from any time. Because this mail downloading all Mail. Go to settings in email and accounts. Tap on account that have a problem. And set the download new content to from,last 2,weeks.

Comment: I have my mail set to download for all time, and have never seen this issue on any of my accounts

Comment: Also Gmail? A would assume this is due to the "fake" IMAP implementation that Google does, but that's only speculation.